# Plotting violin plots: when I add a sample to be displayed, the violin plots no longer show up

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display my results using violin plot and box plot at the same time.

I am using cell count to display the number of immune cells in different cancer samples/groups. When I plot the expression for 4 samples, everything works. When I add another sample (GTEx_M2), the violin plots for all other 4 samples disappear and I end up with only the box plots.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
Cibersort7 = structure(list(
  Hot_M1 = c(0.0214400757119873, 0.170557805230298, 0.0804456569076382, 
             0.0893978598771954, 0.134477669028274, 0, 0.0525708788146097, 
             0.0511711964723951, 0.126904881120795, 0.0485101553521798, 
             0.170894800822398, 0.106555021195299, 0.0970104286070479, 
             0.115825265978309, 0.0427923320117795, 0.0733825856784013, 
             0.0111265771852828, 0.0657019859547462, 0.11656416302191,
             0.172002238486688, 0.0154591596631105, 0.0350445248592811, 
             0.0795539781894198, 0.0781276090630857, 0.0087982313041526, 
             0.0289274652853823, 0.0712661645666698, 0.0435482190581647, 
             0.0455556872660798, 0.0871522448556361), 
  Cold_M1 = c(0.0346024087291239, 0.0201947741817111, 0.0306194109725081, 
              0.0277445612030966, 0.00905915199266666, 0.00939058305405205, 
              0.0146535473252646, 0.0159980760737253, 0.147670469457772, 
              0.0426119074182886, 0.0219251208462312, 0.0128996237306264, 
              0.0094816829459359, 0.0219336027293415, 0.0438220246067735, 
              0.00950926112282649, 0.0838386603270565, 0.0486661009213444, 
              0.00651564872414969, 0.00110323590537234, 0.0807125087307139, 0, 
              0.037709808301658, 0, 0.0898041410439557, 0.0417739517920607, 0, 
              0.0202168551193018, 0.00176008746063679, 0.0161337603014608), 
  Hotnorm_M1 = c(0.00622155478760928, 0.00864956989565159, 0.0245812979257332, 
                 0.0339687958970202, 8e-04, 0, 0.0582086801600888, 0, 
                 0.03481918582501, 0.021338008027511, 0.0157360408231509, 
                 0.00489068636912568, 0.0281166183638247, 0.0162726467268935, 
                 0.0415769266772567, 0, 0.00344830695596762, 0.00196737745405557, 
                 0.0075141479562764, 0.0232464687737552, 0, 0, 0.0289423690350636, 
                 0.0218584208695064, 0.0255945495324721, 4e-04, 0.0221942067802419, 
                 0.00476738514342175, 0.00722699142988291, 0.00974645683928458), 
  Coldnorm_M1 = c(0.0280536098964266, 0.0261826834038114, 0.0150413750071331, 0, 
                  0.0199730743908202, 0.0115748800373456, 0.0275674859254823, 
                  0.0168847795974374, 0.0140281070945953, 0.00907861159279308, 
                  0, 0, 0, 0.0453414461512909, 0, 0.00730963773612433, 
                  0.0236424416792874, 0.0866914356225127, 0.0246339344582405, 
                  0.00881531992455549, 0.0140744199322424, 0, 0, 0, 
                  0.0319211626770028, 0.00155291355277603, 0.00295913497381517, 
                  0.00738775271575955, 0.0179786878323852, 0.00442919920031897), 
  GTEx_M1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
              0, 0, 0, 0.00551740159760184, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -30L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is a small part of my data that still shows the same issue I see.

```
y_axis  = list(na.omit(Cibersort7$Hot_M1), 
               na.omit(Cibersort7$Cold_M1), 
               na.omit(Cibersort7$Hotnorm_M1), 
               na.omit(Cibersort7$Coldnorm_M1), 
               na.omit(Cibersort7$GTEx_M1))
groupname = groupexpression = data = violinPlot  = pairwise_results = list(5)

for (i in 1:5){
  groupname[[i]] = as.factor(colnames(Cibersort7[, i]))
  groupexpression[[i]] = y_axis[[i]]
  data[[i]] = data.frame("Sample" = groupname[[i]], 
                         "Expression" = groupexpression[[i]])
}
dataframe = do.call(rbind, data)
dataframe$Sample = as.factor(dataframe$Sample)

my_comparisons = list(c("Hot_M1", "Cold_M1"),
                      c("Hot_M1", "Hotnorm_M1"), 
                      c("Hot_M1", "GTEx_M1"),
                      c("Cold_M1", "Coldnorm_M1"),
                      c("Cold_M1", "GTEx_M1"))

violinPlot = ggplot(dataframe, 
                    aes(x =Sample, y = Expression, fill = Sample)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE) + 
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, fill="white") + 
  labs(title ="Distribution of M2 Macrophages", 
       x = "Tissue Samples", y = "Cibersort Count") + 
  theme_classic()

violinPlot
```

Here is how my violin plots look like:

[image: plot 1]

Here is how they look like before adding the GTEx data:

[image: plot 2]

And here's GTEx violin plots when displayed alone:

[image: plot 3]

I understand that my GTEx data is zero but why do the violin plots disappear?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the data there? Also make sure that your `ggplot` code work with that sample dataset.

Comment: I just did @Tung

Comment: Actually based on your sample data (which has only 2 valid values per group), no violin plot is plotted for any group at all...

Comment: I just added a more representative data set. Thanks for baring with me! I also added more plots to illustrate the issue better

Answer (score 0):

`geom_violin` has an argument named `scale`, which takes on the default value `"area"`. From `?geom_violin`:

> if "area" (default), all violins have the same area (before trimming
>   the tails). If "count", areas are scaled proportionally to the number
>   of observations. If "width", all violins have the same maximum width.

Since GTEx's Expression values are concentrated at 0, its density peaks sharply at that value. We can see it more obviously in a normal density plot, with each sample's line overlaid atop one another:

```
ggplot(dataframe,
       aes(x = Expression, color = Sample)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: density plot]

With the default `scale = "area"` argument, including GTEx in the data means the violin plot for all other samples becomes a lot skinnier, & hence become almost completely covered by the boxplots. You'd still be able to see them if you comment out the boxplot layer.

You can set `scale = "width"` instead if you want comparable visibility between each violin. You may also want to highlight this to your target audience if you choose this option, as `scale = "area"` tends to be more common, & people may feel confused when some violins appear clearly larger than others.

```
ggplot(dataframe, 
       aes(x = Sample, y = Expression, fill = Sample)) + 
  geom_violin(trim = FALSE, scale = "width") +
  geom_boxplot(width=0.1, fill="white") +
  labs(title ="Distribution of M2 Macrophages", 
       x = "Tissue Samples", y = "Cibersort Count") + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image: violin plot]

**p.s.** You can simplify your data processing steps, which are (from what I can tell) essentially a conversion from wide to long format. The usual way to do this is via `melt` (from reshape2 package) or `gather` (from tidyr package). Here's a possible implementation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- Cibersort7 %>%
  gather(Sample, Expression) %>%
  mutate(Sample = factor(Sample, levels = colnames(Cibersort7)))

> all.equal(dataframe, as.data.frame(df2))
[1] TRUE
```

**p.p.s.** If there are multiple people commenting in your thread & you don't @ anyone in your reply, no one is going to get any notification about it, which is rather a waste if you've gone through all the trouble of improving your question. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for an explanation of how the system works.